# display captured image from photocam

Tags: jsf, primefaces

am trying to replicate the example given in 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/multimedia/photoCam.xhtml
but its not displaying the captured image.

Comment: Sorry to hear that

Comment: You have to show the code for anyone to help